# Connect to microsoft graph API

Tags: python, azure

I have created an `azure` application using the `Microsoft azure` platform.

using the below script I make an attempt to connect to the API using the credentials given when creating the `azure` application.

```
from O365 import Account
credentials = ('azureApp_clientId', 'azureApp_clientSecret')

account = Account(credentials)
if account.authenticate(scopes=['Mail.Read']):
   print('Authenticated!')
```

When the script runs it returns a URL to add to a browser and give consent..

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?xxxxxxxxxx
```

When i paste the URL into my browser it does nothing and returns a blank page..

This is my redirect URI in the `azure` app
[image]

What am I missing??

Docs to o365 Lib here *https://pypi.org/project/O365/*

**Update**

```
from O365 import Account

credentials = ('myclientID')

account = Account(credentials, auth_flow_type = 'public')
if account.authenticate(scopes = ['Mail.Read']):
   print('Authenticated!')
   mailbox = account.mailbox()
   inbox = mailbox.inbox_folder()
   for message in inbox.get_messages():
       print(message)
```

**Update**

[image]

Comment: Please refer to https://github.com/O365/python-o365#oauth-authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the configuration of the application `azure` (you register the application as Mobile and desktop applications), you should use the method [`Authenticate on behalf of a user (public)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0) to do auth and should not provide `client_secret.` For more details, please refer to [here](https://github.com/O365/python-o365#authentication) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-register-app-v2).

For example

```
from O365 import Account

credentials = ('<your client_id>',)

account = Account(credentials,auth_flow_type='public')
if account.authenticate(scopes==['Mail.Read'] ):
   print('Authenticated!')
   mailbox = account.mailbox()
   inbox = mailbox.inbox_folder()
   for message in inbox.get_messages():
       print(message)
```

[image]

---

#Update
My configuration
[image]

Comment: I followed the instructions and your script am getting `ValueError: Provide client id only for public flow credentials` now

Comment: I just realise what I have done. `credentials = ('myclientID')` needs to be `credentials = ('myclientID',)`

Comment: @JamesCook Yes you should define `credentials ` as `('myclientID',)`. Do you have any other concerns? if you have no other concerns, could you please accept it as an answer?

Comment: the code is now producing the URL but when I paste into a browser it asked for permission then did nothing when I accepted.

Comment: @JamesCook When consent is given, the page will redirect to "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient" by default with a url query param called 'code'.

Comment: when I paste the redirect URL into the console It returns `Unable to fetch auth token. Error: (invalid_client) AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret`

Comment: @JamesCook Could you please check if which Platform you use in your AD application?

Comment: @JamesCook  according to your new configuration,  we need to provide `Client_secret` and update code as `credentials = ('azureApp_clientId', 'azureApp_clientSecret')

account = Account(credentials)`. If you do not want to provide `client_secret`, please check my configuration